# CSS - Placing content of a child element in the parent

Tags: css

I'm trying to create a print stylesheet for a web form that users fill out by hand and then copy to the web version. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to print my select list options. It only prints whichever option is currently selected.

Is it possible with CSS (JavaScript isn't an option) to extract the content from the select options and place them in a parent element?  I'm thinking something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="parentDiv">
    <select>
        <option value="Option 1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
@media print{
    #parentDiv:before {
        content: child.attr(value);
    }
}
```

That's obviously not correct, but is there a way to actually do this?  Or any other JavaScript-free way to print out the options?

NOTE: The page is dynamically rendered, and I am not able to render additional "hidden" `<div>` elements to unhide in the print css, so that solution won't work for me.

THANKS!

Comment: No, it's not possible with just CSS, but you [can with some js](http://css-tricks.com/making-selects-printable/)

Comment: If the page is dynamically rendered, how come you can't dynamically render additional hidden divs?

Comment: @MrLister I would, but the code to build the form is so complex that it would be a significant undertaking to add the additional divs without either breaking something or missing some obscure scenario.